# Summation simplification on exponentiaion

Tags: summation, exponential-sum

I would like to ask help for the following question:

Simplify $$\sum_{x=0}^{+\infty}{e^{-x/\mu}}$$

Will integration work here? Meaning, can I do it this way?

$$\sum_{x=0}^{+\infty}{e^{-x/\mu}}=\lim_{a\rightarrow+\infty}\sum_{x=0}^{a}{e^{-x/\mu}}=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-x/\mu}dx$$

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a geometric series, with common ratio $r = e^{-1/\mu}$.  It converges if and only if $|r|<1$ (this includes the case where  $r$ is complex).  If it converges, the easiest way to remember its value is

$$        \frac{\mbox{[First Term In Series]}}{1-\mbox{[Common Ratio]}}.             $$

That way you don't have to fuss about whether the series starts at $x=0$ or $x=1$ and details like that.

What you are doing with the integral *might* tell you whether or not the series converges, but it definitely won't give you the value of the series if it converges.  With a geometric series like this you don't need the Integral Test (that's what you are attempting to use).  I would save the Integral Test for problems where you need it. And still, the Integral Test can tell you whether a series converges but to my knowledge it never gives you the value of a convergent series.

Answer (score 3):

For $\vert a \vert < 1$, we have
$$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} a^x = \dfrac1{1-a}$$
Now set $a=e^{-1/\mu}$.

Comment: You should probably add that $|a|<1$.

Comment: @Mercy Added, Your Honour.

Comment: You are welcome your Highness!